# Bland-Altman plot correction for proportional bias

Tags: bland-altman-plot

I am comparing 2 measurement methods with the Bland-Altman plot methodology.
I found a proportional bias between the 2 measurement systems, by the regression model:

difference = intercept + b1*average

The parameters of the regression are:

intercept = 18.44

b1 = -0.27

both are significant.

How do I correct my new measurement scores with the parameters I found in the regression, so that I that both measurements have the same scores?